# How to write points coordintates not index?

Tags: python

I have a code that takes set of points of a point cloud and detects multiple planes. the code gives me the equation of planes which have points more than a certain number (here 4000) belonging to it. All I need is to write the coordinates of points (not their index) belonging to these planes in a text file.

The code:

```
def ReadPlyPoint(fname):
    pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(fname)
    return PCDToNumpy(pcd)

def NumpyToPCD(xyz):
    pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(xyz)
    return pcd

def PCDToNumpy(pcd):
    return np.asarray(pcd.points)

def PlaneRegression(points, threshold=0.01, init_n=3, iter=1000):
    pcd = NumpyToPCD(points)
    w, index = pcd.segment_plane(threshold, init_n, iter)
    [a, b, c, d] = w
    if len(index) > 4000 :
        print (f'plane equation: {a:.2f}x + {b:.2f}y + {c:.2f}z + {d:.2f} = 0')
    return w, index

def DetectMultiPlanes(points, min_ratio=0.05, threshold=0.01, iterations=1000):
    plane_list = []
    N = len(points)
    target = points.copy()
    count = 0

    while count < (1 - min_ratio) * N:
        w, index = PlaneRegression(target, threshold=threshold, init_n=3, iter=iterations)

        count += len(index)
        plane_list.append((w, target[index]))
        target = np.delete(target, index, axis=0)

    return plane_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import random

    points = ReadPlyPoint('segdown.ply')
    results = DetectMultiPlanes(points, min_ratio=0.05, threshold=0.01, iterations=3000)

    planes = []
    colors = []
    for _, plane in results:

        r = random.random()
        g = random.random()
        b = random.random()

        color = np.zeros((plane.shape[0], plane.shape[1]))
        color[:, 0] = r
        color[:, 1] = g
        color[:, 2] = b

        planes.append(plane)
        colors.append(color)

    planes = np.concatenate(planes, axis=0)
    colors = np.concatenate(colors, axis=0)

    DrawResult(planes, colors)
```

I have tried this but the points stored don't belong to the detected planes :

```
def PlaneRegression(points, threshold=0.01, init_n=3, iter=1000):
    f = open('primitives_only1.txt', 'a')
    pcd = NumpyToPCD(points)
    w, index = pcd.segment_plane(threshold, init_n, iter)
    [a, b, c, d] = w
    if len(index) > 4000 :
         for i in range(len(index)):
            f.write("{} \n".format(str(points[i])))
        f.close()
    return w, index
```

[detected planes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wibwM.jpg)

Comment: What is your question? Or, rather, what is the desired input and output?

Comment: There is not enough code in your question for anyone to answer it.

Comment: this is all the code by the way.

Comment: The output is a text file has the coordinates of points belonging to planes where each plane has at least 4000 points

Comment: @martineau check the attached image. All I need is the coordinates of points forming for example the green plane

Comment: When I said there wasn't enough code, I was referring to the `o3d` stuff. Since I don't know what `NumpyToPCD()` is returning, I therefore don't know what's being put into `w`, and `index`. Apparently it's not what you think, otherwise `str(points[i])` would be the coordinates.